# upload image and other data to nodejs in react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios

I'm having trouble when I want to upload images to my backend, when I post with Postman there's no problem but when I implement it in React Native the code has problems,

The following is for the request code in React Native

this is for POST requests

```
 const handlekirimPengaduan = () => {
    // console.log('judul : ', jdlLaporan);
    // console.log('isi : ', isiLaporan);
    // console.log('foto : ', foto);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
      'id_pengaduan',
      `${today.getFullYear()}${today.getHours()}${today.getMinutes()}${today.getSeconds()}`,
    );
    formData.append('nik', nik.toString());
    formData.append('jdl_laporan', jdlLaporan);
    formData.append('isi_laporan', isiLaporan);
    // formData.append('foto', foto);
    formData.append('tgl_pengaduan', Today);
    formData.append('file', {
      uri: foto.assets[0].uri,
      type: foto.assets[0].type,
      name: foto.assets[0].fileName,
    });
    // console.log(formData)
  

    kirim_pengaduan({ 
      // id_pengaduan: `${today.getFullYear()}${today.getHours()}${today.getMinutes()}${today.getSeconds()}`,
      // nik: nik.toString(),
      // jdl_laporan: jdlLaporan,
      // isi_laporan: isiLaporan,
      // tgl_pengaduan: Today,
      formData
      
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log('result:', result);
        if (result.status == 200) {
          alert(
            'Laporan Anda Berhasil Dibuat, Silahkan menunggu info selanjutnya',
          );
          navigation.replace('Home');
        } else {
          alert(result.msg);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert('error', err);
      });
  };
```

this is for inserting the image and setting it to state

```
 const openGalery = async () => {
    const images = await launchImageLibrary(options);
   
    setFoto(images);
    // setFoto(images.assets[0].fileName)
    // console.log(images.assets[0].fileName)
    // console.log(formData);
    // console.log(images.assets[0].uri)

    // let res = await fetch(
    //   'http://localhost//webservice/user/uploadImage',
    //   {
    //     method: 'post',
    //     body: data,
    //     headers: {
    //       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; ',
    //     },
    //   }
    // );
  };
```

I have tried changing the request method, then trying to set the json so that it can be read by the backend but still can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foto.assets[0].uri` is a reference to image data on device memory but does not contain the actual image data.

A simple solution is uploading **base64** data and `react-native-image-picker` return base64 data when `includeBase64` set to `true`

Comment: thanks i got the point, and already solved

Comment: You can approve the answer as it help to solve the issue